# SQL Server, CONTEXT_INFO(), and varchar size

Tags: sql-server, context-info

In table `users` I have a column `username` of datatype `varchar(50)`. The table has no records. I insert a new record with `A` for the username. The following returns what I would expect:

```
SELECT username, LEN(username) 
FROM users 
WHERE id = 1 -- returns: A, 1
```

So far so good.

Now I update table users from a trigger on another table, using the value from `CONTEXT_INFO()`:

```
set @context = cast('B' as varbinary(128))
set CONTEXT_INFO @context

update some_other_table 
set x = 'y' 
where id = 97
```

In the trigger for `some_other_table` I do:

```
DECLARE @context VARCHAR(128)

SELECT 
    @context = CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR(128)) 
FROM 
    master.dbo.SYSPROCESSES 
WHERE 
    SPID = @@SPID

DECLARE @user VARCHAR(50) = LEFT(@context, 50)

UPDATE users 
SET username = LTRIM(RTRIM(@user)) 
WHERE id = 1
```

The username is correctly set to "B", but the following now returns 50:

```
SELECT 
    username, LEN(username) 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    id = 1 -- returns: B, 50
```

The solution, when populating the context, is to do:

```
set @context = cast('B' + replicate(' ', 126) as varbinary(128))
```

But why do I need to do this?

When I don't pad the `CONTEXT_INFO` with spaces what is happening that updating using its value will cause the resulting length to be 50 (even if I `ltrim` and `rtrim` the single character value before updating)?

And why must I pad my `CONTEXT_INFO` to 127 bytes total, not 128? For every character over 127, 1 character is truncated from the value originally set on `CONTEXT_INFO`

Note: ANSI_PADDING is enabled

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
declare @user varchar(50) = left(@context, 50)
UPDATE users set username = ltrim(rtrim(@user)) WHERE id = 1
```

you defined `@user` to be 50 characters.  Since the `CONTEXT_INFO` itself is 128 bytes, the contents of `@user` will be the letter `B` padded by 49 null `CHAR(0)` characters.  `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` will not remove null characters, which are not whitespace, so they have no effect on `@user`.

If you want to remove the `NULL` character you can try this (assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or later):

```
UPDATE users SET username = REPLACE(@user, char(0), '')
```

Comment: Short of casting the value to a type that doesn't allow the NULL byte, is there an easy way to remove all trailing NULL bytes?

Comment: If you select 50 bytes from a 128 byte null-padded `CONTEXT_INFO` then what would you like to have as padding instead of `NULL`?  If you don't want padding then just select the exact length.

Comment: But how can I know how many non-NULL characters were passed into the CONTEXT_INFO? In my example the passed value is hard coded, but in live code the CONTEXT_INFO is populated using dynamic data.

Comment: Because my trigger can't know if there is 1 or 127 bytes in CONTEXT_INFO (in my example above its hard coded, but in production it will be dynamic) I ended up doing the following:

    set `@start = charindex(char(0), `@context)
    if `@start > 0        set `@context = left(`@context, `@start)

This is likely better than calculating how many space characters to append to context_info in every place that might set a value on the context_info.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but there are two ways of retreiving `CONTEXT_INFO`: either directly with `CONTEXT_INFO()`, or from `sys.dm_exec_sessions`. The latter is not padded with '0' characters.

```
declare @c varbinary(128)
select  @c = convert(varbinary(128), 'Test context')
set CONTEXT_INFO @c
go

-- option 1: padded with '0'
declare @value varchar(128)
select  @value = convert(varchar(128), CONTEXT_INFO())
select  @value context, len(@value) length
go

-- option 2: NOT padded with '0'
declare @value varchar(128)
select  @value = convert(varchar(128), context_info)
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@SPID
select  @value context, len(@value) length
go
```

Query result.

```
context         length
--------------- -----------
Test context    128

(1 row affected)

context         length
--------------- -----------
Test context    12

(1 row affected)
```

Alternatively, as of SQL Server 2016 you can also use `SESSION_CONTEXT()`, which allows you to specify key-value pairs, instead of a single binary blob.